# Change current list element on link click using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change current tab on a link click. I have something like this:

[image]

So when I click on the next or previous link I want to change active tab.
I guess this can be done in JavaScript, but since I'm complete beginner, I can preform only easiest tasks.

This is the HTML used for building this part of page:

```
<div class="grey-box-wrap">
    <div class="top">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="prev"><i></i>previous week</a>
        <span class="center">February 04 - February 10, 2013 (week 6)</span>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="next">next week<i></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <ul class="days">
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <b>Feb 04</b>
                    <!-- <i>7.5</i> -->
                    <span>monday</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <b>Feb 06</b>
                    <!-- <i>7.5</i> -->
                    <span>tuesday</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <b>Feb 06</b>
                    <!-- <i>7.5</i> -->
                    <span>wednesday</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <b>Feb 07</b>
                    <!-- <i>7.5</i> -->
                    <span>thursday</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <b>Feb 08</b>
                    <!-- <i>7.5</i> -->
                    <span>friday</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <b>Feb 09</b>
                    <!-- <i>0.0</i> -->
                    <span>saturday</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="last">
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <b>Feb 10</b>
                    <!-- <i>0.0</i> -->
                    <span>sunday</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-wrapper">
```

This is CSS:

```
.grey-box-wrap .bottom .days li.active a, .grey-box-wrap .bottom .days li:hover a {
color: white;
}

.grey-box-wrap .bottom .days li a {
color: #666666;
}

.grey-box-wrap .top {
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
padding: 0 10px;
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
margin-bottom: 10px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grey-box-wrap .top .prev {
float: left;
}

.grey-box-wrap .top .next {
float: right;
text-align: right;
}

.grey-box-wrap .top .prev, .grey-box-wrap .top .next {
width: 25%;
color: #f1592a;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
}

.grey-box-wrap .bottom .days li.active, .grey-box-wrap .bottom .days li:hover {
border: solid 1px #f1592a;
}

.grey-box-wrap .bottom .days li {
float: left;
margin-right: 2px;
width: 99px;
padding: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
-ms-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
-o-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
border-bottom: none;
background: white;
}
```

And this is my attempt to get list elements in JS:

Can someone help me with this, or give me a suggestion on what's the easiest or best way to preform this kind of task?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you made an attempt to solve this yourself which you could add to your question?

Comment: Include the relevant CSS as well.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well I did, but only thing I was able to do is to get list elements on click... and I guess that doesn't helps a lot...I can post that test code too, but it doesn't preform much...:(

Comment: show us what you have done and where you are facing problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to complete this. I've tried to keep it as simple as possible and have added comments so you can understand each line.

Try something like this with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // check document is ready
    $('li a').click(function() { // catch a click on a list link
        $('li').removeClass('active'); // remove all current instances of active
        $(this).parent().addClass('active'); // add the class active to the item you clicked
    });
});
```

You can view the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dbr8dxmu/

Comment: you don't need to loop through all `li's` to remove class. `$('li').removeClass('active');` will do.

Comment: @Stewartside Hey thank you so much! This is working really well. And even more thank you on comments you gave with code. Now I will be able to preform this kind of tasks by myself. Thanks once more! :D

Comment: Cheers. Have amended my answer to show your recommendation

Comment: @nemo_87 no problem. A ticked answer would be lovely :D

Comment: @Stewartside Ticked answer coming in just 30 seconds :D

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to call javascript code upon clicking your link which finds out the next element to be highlighted. For example when the link 'Next' which you want to use to change the active tab to the next tab is clicked, your code could look like this:

```
var tabs = $("days li"); //get all your tabs
var firstTab= $(tabs[0]); //this represents the first tab

tabs.each(function(index){
  if($(this).hasClass('active'){
    $(this).toggleClass(active);
    if(index < tabs.length - 1){
      //the active tab has a next tab following it, activate it
      $(tabs[index+1]).toggleClass('active'); 
      return false;
    } else{
      //the last tab was the active tab, so we have to start from the first tab
      firstTab.toggleClass('active');
      return false
    }
  }
});
```

Now you can put this into a function `selectNextTab` and tell your browser to call this function when your link was clicked. If you have other buttons that are supposed to do the same in a different place just make sure they have the 'next' class.

```
$(".next").click(function () {
  selectNextTab();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(".next").click(function () {

    var currntIndex = $(".active").index();
    if (currntIndex < $(".days>li").length-1) {
        $(".active").next("li").addClass("active");
        $("li").eq(currntIndex).removeClass("active");
    }

});

$(".prev").click(function () {
    var currntIndex = $(".active").index();
    if (currntIndex) {
        $(".active").prev("li").addClass("active");
        $("li").eq(currntIndex).removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n9r2j83v/1/)**